# running infinite loop in linux kernel module

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I have make a module in which i would like to run an infinite loop till I don't unload the module . Presently if I do rmmod it gives me notice that module is still busy and after some time kernel panics.

```
while(1)
{
    .......

}
```

Is there any trick through which I could run infinite loop till I unload the module.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a good idea. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Perhaps consider using the timer interface instead; http://kerneldeveloper.drupalgardens.com/addtimer-function

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In which context does this loop run? This is a very important question.

If `init_module` runs it, then the `insmod` process will never end, which is quite bad.
If some system call runs it, then the system call won't return, and it will also be bad.
In both cases, there's no way to kill the process (not even `kill -9`).
If you're doing it in a softIRQ handler (or, worse, hardIRQ handler), you'll hang the system.

If you do it in a kernel thread, which is dedicated to this task, you have a chance to get it right.
But if you don't want to hog the CPU completely, you need to call the scheduler and let it run other tasks. `msleep_interruptible` is a nice way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure this would work, but instead of `while(1)`, use `while(notStopped)`, which is set to `1` at first, and set it to `0` in `stop_module()`.