# What will happen if a busy infinite loop starts in kernel module?

Tags: linux, kernel

I want to know what will happen if a busy infinite loop starts in Linux kernel module. CPU will be dead?
Like below:

```
while(1)
    ;
```

Is the scheduler still works for kernel module/thread?
If I use spin for busy wait and the resource is never available, what will happen? CPU dead?

Does single core or multi-core have different results?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10223295/running-infinite-loop-in-linux-kernel-module

Comment: If you are not in critical section with disabled preemption, the thread with inifinite loop can be preempted, as usual. In any case scheduler still works.